# How to use array in javascript and print it out on webpage

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing my assignment but I haven't used javascript on HTML before.

This is my HTML file(list.html).

```
 <main>
      <section class="main center">
        <!-- Start your code here -->
        <h2>HTML Lists</h2>
        <div id="fruit">
          <body>
            <h2>Fruit</h2>
          </body>
        </div>
         
        <div id="directories">
          <body>
            <h2>Directories</h2>
          </body>
        </div>

        <!-- End your code here  -->
      </section>
    </main>
```

and this is my javascript file(list.js).

```
const fruits = ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Pineapples', 'Mangos'];
/* I wrote this part (var i = 0; i < 6; i ++)
console.log fruits(i);*/
const directory = [
  { type: 'file', name: 'file1.txt' },
  { type: 'file', name: 'file2.txt' },
  {
    type: 'directory',
    name: 'HTML Files',
    files: [
      { type: 'file', name: 'file1.html' },
      { type: 'file', name: 'file2.html' }
    ]
  },
  { type: 'file', name: 'file3.txt' },
  {
    type: 'directory',
    name: 'JavaScript Files',
    files: [
      { type: 'file', name: 'file1.js' },
      { type: 'file', name: 'file2.js' },
      { type: 'file', name: 'file3.js' }
    ]
  }
];
```

I have to print out fruits array, but I don't know how to make it print out on the webpage. I can only check it on dev tool.

Comment: Consider doing your own [research](https://stackoverflow.com/search) so you can learn that way as well.

Answer (score 0):

This code dynamically adds fruits list into your html code.

```js
const fruits = ["Apples", "Oranges", "Pears", "Grapes", "Pineapples", "Mangos"];


let liList = "";
fruits.forEach(item => {
    liList = liList + `<li>${item}</li>`;
});

document.querySelector("#insertFruits").innerHTML = liList;
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="main center">
    <!-- Start your code here -->
    <h2>HTML Lists</h2>
    <div id="fruit">

      <body>
        <h2>Fruit</h2>
        <ul id="insertFruits">
        </ul>
      </body>
    </div>

    <div id="directories">

      <body>
        <h2>Directories</h2>
      </body>
    </div>

    <!-- End your code here  -->
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: `innerHTML` is not recommended to be used.

Comment: modern browser are secure against XSS from innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

For rendering array of items first we have to get body to our script, because we are going to attach list to body.
`const body = document.querySelector("body");`
Then we are looping array and creating div tag,
`const div = document.createElement("div");` (btw it can be any tag)
And we give a value to `div`
`div.innerText = fruit`
And in the end attach `div` to `body`

```
const body = document.querySelector("body");
          fruits.forEach((fruit) => {
            const div = document.createElement("div");
            div.innerText = fruit;
            body.appendChild(div);
          });
```

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can print array in your javascript file by adding below line just after 'const fruits' declaration :
`document.getElementById("fruitList").innerHTML=fruits;`

So, if you want to print the fruits array just below the text 'Fruit', then add a 'div' element within your 'fruit' 'div' with id 'fruitList' as shown below, so it will print the array below it:

```
    <div id="fruit">
      <body>
        <h2>Fruit</h2>
        <div id="fruitList">
        </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </div>
```